# Serialization Writing/Reading to File

Tags: java, serialization, save, loading

I have a strange bug when executing my code. The first time I save the level, the code properly writes to the file. Upon running the game, the level is properly loaded. However, the second time I try saving on a level that was previously loaded, the save file's arraylists become null. The code DOES NOT throw an error, I noticed only the ArrayList filled with entities, not the level itself, became null, hence does not properly load the game the second time around.
Here is my code:

```
public void save() {

    try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(fileName, false))) {

        out.writeObject(object);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("There was a problem saving " + object);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public Object load() {

    try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(fileName))) {
        return in.readObject();

    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("There was a problem loading " + object);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

The following methods are called when expected:

```
public static void saveGame() {
    level.save();
    System.out.println("SAVED");
    System.out.println(level.load());
}

public static void load() {
    if (level.load() != null) {
        Level.level1 = (Level) level.load();
        System.out.println(Level.level1);
        System.out.println("LOADED");
    }
}
```

The levels themselves are static, I'm not sure if that has any special rules. Here is the snippet of the Level instance data if that is needed:

```
protected List<Mob> mobs = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Mob>();
protected List<Player> players = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Player>();
private String imagePath;
private transient BufferedImage image;
public static Level level1 = new LordHillsboroughsDomain();
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with a new instance of the level overwriting the saved level, but I just can't seem to figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: On a side note. You should close your `ObjectStreams` (use a `finally` block)

Comment: @stacksonstacks I think that Wookiederk might be using a version of java which has "try with resources" and `Closable`s and stuff, but if not you are correct

Comment: Could it be something to do with the way object references within classes are serialized? Have you checked that the output file has no problems writing the ArrayLists?

Comment: (stupid question asked then... ignore this comment!)

Comment: @BenKnoble The first time around, the ArrayList of Mobs is saved correctly, and they are loaded properly. I don't think the file has a problem writing the arraylist for this reason. But, deleting the old file and recreating a new one seems to be a temporary solution.

Comment: Have you actually looked at what the file says? Is it some kind of xml where you can tell what you're looking at or is it some kind of encryption that isn't understandable?

Comment: It is not understandable.

Comment: So you save and load; fine. You save again, and on the load, the ArrayLists are screwed up? Maybe you need to serialize each of the ArrayLists individually and the reload them on their own as well...

Comment: your save method doesn't show what `object` is.  your load method is called multiple times but never assigns the result to anything...

Comment: @BenKnoble I'll try doing that.

Comment: @BenKnoble Serialized data is not XML, and serializing an array works just as well as serializing all its members. That's enough guesswork for now thanks.

Comment: @EJP im just trying to help; im not perfect and clearly not incredibly knowledgeable. I know theres more stuff. But i thought about what i know. Plus, i suggested some things to try or try searching. No harm done.

Comment: @BenKnoble You added zero value and sowed a lot of irrelevant confusion. I don't call that 'no harm done'.

Comment: @EJP  if you look my comments were valued. Jus' saying.